# Awk syntax error pattern matching

Tags: awk

I want to match every empty line, and when it is an empty line, i want to go to the next line.
The problem is when i type

```
/^$/ { next }
```

it always gives me a syntaxt error. It always refers to the first '{'. I thought this was the correct syntax. Can anyone help me please?

My script:

```
BEGIN{
    FS="  "
    matching=0
    num=0
}
{
    /^$/ { next }
    if(matching==1 && num>=NF){
        print("")
        matching=0
    }
    if(match($NF,type)>0){
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            printf($i)
        }
        printf("\n")
        num=NF
        matching=1
        next
    }
    if(matching==1){
        for(i=1;i<=NF-num;i++){
            printf("  ")
        }
        printf($NF)
        printf("\n")
    }
}
END{

}
```

This is my script

Comment: Strange, `awk '/^$/ {next} {print}' file` works fine to me. Anyway, you can also do use the number of fields. If it is 0, then skip: `awk 'NF==0 {next} {print}' file` or even `awk '!NF {next} {print}' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui or just `awk NF file`. `:P`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use the `pattern {action}` syntax from *within* an `{action}` block there.

You need to move your `/^$/ {next}` line outside of the action block you are starting on line 6 (by moving it above that opening <kbd>{</kbd> to get what you want. Or use the `if` style matching in the action block.

Your script:

```
BEGIN{
    FS="  "
    matching=0
    num=0
}
{ # <---- This starts an action block.
    /^$/ { next } # <----- This is a pattern/action pair.
    if(matching==1 && num>=NF){
        print("")
        matching=0
    }
    if(match($NF,type)>0){
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            printf($i)
        }
        printf("\n")
        num=NF
        matching=1
        next
    }
    if(matching==1){
        for(i=1;i<=NF-num;i++){
            printf("  ")
        }
        printf($NF)
        printf("\n")
    }
}
END {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your script has several issues, commented below:

```
BEGIN{
    FS="  "
    matching=0     # No need to init variables to zero, this is default behavior.
    num=0          # Ditto.
}
{
    /^$/ { next }  # You can't just use "condition { action }" when you're already
                   # inside an awk action block. Move this outside of the action
                   # block or change it to "if (/^$/) { next }"
    if(matching==1 && num>=NF){
        print("")  # print is a builtin not a function. Just do print "".
        matching=0
    }
    if(match($NF,type)>0){
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            printf($i)    # printf is a builtin, not a function and NEVER put input data
                          # where the printf formatting string should be. Change this to
                          # printf "%s", $i
        }
        printf("\n")      # print ""
        num=NF
        matching=1
        next
    }
    if(matching==1){
        for(i=1;i<=NF-num;i++){
            printf("  ")  # printf "  "
        }
        printf($NF)       # printf "%s", $NF
        printf("\n")      # print ""
    }
}
END{                      # unused and unnecessary, remove this section.

}
```

I suspect if you posted some sample input and expected output we could help you write a better (more concise and more idomatic) script.